# Set Generate automatic URL alias during import in Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

how to set 'Generate automatic URL alias' for my terms during Feeds import?

[image]

I tried to set 1 or '1' in URL (url) field but it does not work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use views bulk operation module and then you can update nodes or taxonomy on the fly via view....

I have the same problem now for nodes...